# Is there any proof for ECDSA signature algorithm?

Tags: signature, dsa, schnorr-signature, schnorr-identification

Related: Is there an interactive version of ECDSA signature protocol like the Schnorr identification protocol?

Comment: [related Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71029/23623)

Comment: Thanks, that answers the original question. Still looking for answers for whether ECDSA has a corresponding interactive protocol.

Comment: A "proof for ECDSA signature algorithm" comes in two parts: Correctness (also called soundness), proving that a legitimate signature is always accepted. And security, per some definition of that (there are several variants) and under some assumptions. Correctness is easy, and given in many expositions of ECDSA; it is e.g. [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Correctness_of_the_algorithm). Security is a hard problem; here is an [article](https://doi.org/10.1145/2976749.2978413) with bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @SEJPM, you can read more about security proofs for DSA/ECDSA family on [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71029/23623) thread.

As for whether there exists an interactive protocol corresponding to DSA/ECDSA à la Schnorr identification/Schnorr signature, not that I am aware of. I would add that this is unlikely for two reasons:

1. The (unfortunate) reason for coming up with DSA/ECDSA was to bypass the patent on Schnorr signatures. Therefore its design was supposed be different enough from Schnorr.
2. If there were some kind of a sigma protocol then it is very likely that this would lead to a security proof (at least in the random-oracle model) as there exist standard methods to construct signatures from identification. Since we don't know a proof, one could say that there probably isn't an interactive protocol either (but this argument is very hand-wavy).