# Is that proved that breaking ECDSA as hard as solving ECDLP?

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, discrete-logarithm

Is that proved that breaking ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) as hard as solving ECDLP(Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem)?

Comment: Does [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71031/11441) answer help?

Comment: not it is not proved such a thing. ECDSA (or DSA) can break  (under some special conditions) by avoiding to solve ECDLP (or DLP resp.). For instance if you know "some" contiguous bits of secret and ephemeral keys of polynomial many signatures you can break ECDSA without solving  ECDLP.