# Prove DSA signature scheme is EUF-CMA secure

Tags: signature, discrete-logarithm, dsa, random-oracle-model, fiat-shamir

I want to prove that the DSA signature scheme is EUF-CMA secure in the random oracle model, if the discrete logarithm problem is hard. I know it can be proved by the following two parts:

> 1. Discrete logarithm problem is hard $\Rightarrow$ DSA identification scheme is UI-PA security
> 2. DSA identification scheme is UI-PA security + $H,F$ are random oracle $\Rightarrow$ DSA signature scheme is EUF-CMA secure

For clarity, the DSA identification protocol and signature algorithm I consider is as follows (use the Fiat-Samir transform to convert the identification protocol into a signature scheme):

**DSA identification protocol**

$PK=(G,p,g,h=g^s),SK=s$

- Prover uniformly selects $r\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$, let $R:=g^r\in G$, and gives $R$ to Verifier.
- Verifier uniformly selects $(e,d)\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p^2$, and gives $(e,d)$ to Prover.
- Prover computes $z:=r^{-1}\cdot(e+d\cdot s)\in\mathbb{Z}_p$, and gives $z$ to Verifier
- Verifier checks whether $R=(g^e\cdot h^d)^{z^{-1}}$. If yes, the verification passes.

**DSA signature scheme**

Two hash functions: $H:\{0,1\}^*\to \mathbb{Z}_p,F:G\to \mathbb{Z}_p$

- Key generation algorithm: $(PK=(G,p,g,h=g^s),SK=s)\leftarrow \mathsf{Gen}(1^\lambda)$
- Signature algorithm: $\sigma\leftarrow\mathsf{Sign}(SK,M)$, message $M\in\{0,1\}^*$

  - Prover uniformly selects $r\leftarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$, let $R:=g^r\in G$
  - Computes $e:=H(M)\in\mathbb{Z}_p$
  - Computes $d:=F(R)\in\mathbb{Z}_p$
  - Computes $z:=r^{-1}\cdot(e+d\cdot s)\in\mathbb{Z}_p$
  - Outputs $\sigma:=(d,z)$
- Verification algorithm: $0/1\leftarrow \mathsf{Vfy}(PK,M,\sigma=(d,z))$

  - Verifier computers $e:=H(M)\in\mathbb{Z}_p$
  - Computes $R:=(g^e\cdot h^d)^{z^{-1}}\in\mathbb{Z}_p$
  - Checks whether $d=F(R)$. If yes, outputs 1; otherwise, outputs 0

I've solved the first part, but I don't know how to prove the **second part**. I found a relevant proof about the Schnorr signature scheme in in Theorem 12.10 on page 454 of [INTRODUCTION TO MODERN CRYPTOGRAPHY](https://eclass.uniwa.gr/modules/document/file.php/CSCYB105/Reading%20Material/%5BJonathan_Katz%2C_Yehuda_Lindell%5D_Introduction_to_Mo%282nd%29.pdf). But unlike the Schnorr signature scheme, the DSA signature scheme uses two hash functions (i.e. $H,F$), which confuses me.

Detailed proofs or ideas are welcome and appreciated :)

Comment: Question is clear now! Your $p$ is noted $q$ in [DSA](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A53%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C700%2C0%5D) or $n$ in [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1). In these your $F$ is a reduction modulo your $p$ of some integer (near) representative of an element of your $G$. So you are studying some theoretical model/variant of DSA/ECDSA. There is literature linked in this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/71031), and [this ref](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/140.pdf#page=18).